# Php $_POST method to get textarea value

Tags: php, post

I am using php to get textarea value using post method but getting a weird result with that let me show you my code

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <textarea id="contact_list" name="contact_list"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

I am entering some names and their email address in the textarea, and everytime i echo the value or textarea it skips the email address and only showing the name let me show the way i am entering value in textarea

```
"name1" <name@email.com>, "name2" <name2@email.com>
```

and once I will echo using php it will only echo the name and will skip the email address.

Comment: It isn't skipping the email, your webbrowser is interpreting it as a tag and it isn't being displayed. Look at the html source.

Comment: Please try this :<br /><br/> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719186/issue-using-post-with-a-textarea">Issue using $_POST with a textarea</a>

Answer (score 42):

Always (always, **always**, I'm [not kidding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)) use `htmlspecialchars()`:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['contact_list']);
```

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your escaping the HTML characters

E.g.

```
// Always check an input variable is set before you use it
if (isset($_POST['contact_list'])) {
    // Escape any html characters
    echo htmlentities($_POST['contact_list']);
}
```

This would occur because of the angle brackets and the browser thinking they are tags.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: i believe htmlentities will work better coz there is no html_entity_encode method

Comment: yea, yea, quick answer before I looked up the real function :P

Answer (score 2):

Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['contact_list']);
```

You can even improve your form processing by stripping all tags with [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and remove all white spaces with [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
function processText($text) {
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    $text = trim($text);
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
    return $text;
}

echo processText($_POST['contact_list']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove some of your textarea class like

```
<textarea name="Address" rows="3" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="Your Address" ></textarea>
```

To

```
<textarea name="Address" rows="3" class="full-width" placeholder="Your Address" ></textarea>
```

It's dependent on your template (Purchased Template).
The developer has included some JavaScript to get the value from correct object on UI,
but class like `input-text` just finds only `$('input[type=text]')`, that's why.

Comment: Please, don't submit the exact same answer to different questions. Flag the question as "duplicate" if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use different id and name parameters, currently you have same here. Please visit the link below for the same, this might be help you :

[Issue using $_POST with a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719186/issue-using-post-with-a-textarea)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ManishKr.Shukla While I agree with your review decision, it's worth mentioning that, this particular link is directing to another question on SO site. So I voted "looks ok".

Comment: @ManishKr.Shukla and user1032613 Thank you for the information. I will take care of that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//My Form
<form id="someform">
        <div class="input-group">
            <textarea placeholder="Post your Comment Here ..." name="post" class="form-control custom-control" rows="3" style="resize:none"></textarea> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">                                            
                <button type="submit" name="post_comment" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Post
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>

//your text area get value to URL
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['post_comment']))
        {
            echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['post']);
        }

    ?>

//print the value using get
echo $_GET['post'];

//url must be like this
http://localhost/blog/home.php?post=asdasdsad&post_comment=

//post value has asdasdsad so it will print to your page
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very simply. Just write your php value code between textarea tag.

```
<textarea id="contact_list"> <?php echo isset($_POST['contact_list']) ? $_POST['contact_list'] : '' ; ?> </textarea>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
<?php /* the php */ ?>
<?php 
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        // must work
        echo $_POST['contact_list'];
    };
?>


 <?php /* and the html */ ?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>teszt</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
            <textarea id="contact_list" name="contact_list"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```