# Issue using $_POST with a textarea

Tags: php, html, post

I have a simple contact form on a website that has 2 text fields, 1 textarea, and 1 hidden field.

For some reason, all the fields POST to a PHP script except the textarea. I have done this a thousand times before and never had this issue.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="scripts/contactform.php" method="post">
<table width="0" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="5" class="gpass">
  <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" maxlength="50" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-mail:</td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Message:</td>
    <td><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value=" <?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>" name="address" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="noround" id="regbut" /><input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" class="noround" id="regbut"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And my script looks like this:

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) 
{
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) 
{
    die("Unable to select database");
}

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
$ipaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
```

I have a few things to process the data underneath this, but that doesn't matter since the `$comment` variable isn't being defined. I've searched the entire script and there are no conflicting variable names.

I am completely stumped on why this is happening. I've successfully processed `textarea`'s on my site multiple times before, so this really is confusing.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: What do you see if you do a `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: Where do you use the `comment` data (I can't see it in your code)? What is in the `$_POST` superglobal? E.g. `var_dump($_POST)`;

Comment: I see this ["message"]=> string(2) "cw"
(cw is what I typed in)

Comment: @PeeHaa, I insert it into a database and also e-mail it later on

Comment: Whoa! "message" or "comment"? Which is it?

Comment: Well it was originally $message, but I was using that variable for an e-mail message later on in the script and it was easier to just change the name of the textarea variable. What's the problem?

Comment: @AndrewDeForest in your HTML you used `comment` as name but in your dump you say you have `message` as name. I say PEBKAC.

Comment: OK I see what you're saying, I could have sworn I checked it over a million times. Oh well, it is working now. Thanks everyone for the input!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I once experienced an error similar to yours. What helped me was to use different `id` and `name` parameters. Try and see for yourself, because you have them identical here.

Comment: Wow, for some reason this worked! Any idea why? I will mark this as answered in a few minutes, just have to wait for the timer.

Thanks!

Comment: No idea, really ... But when that happened to me, I was freaking out and just tried to assign a different id to my field. I was shocked it worked for me back then.

Comment: @craig1231, it happened to me way before HTML5 became known.

Answer (score 1):

Though in your case you don't have the `textarea` set to `disabled`, the reason I found this post was because I wasn't getting a value from a `textarea` that was. So here's a note for anyone else with *that* issue.

To `POST` the value from a `textarea` where you want the field to be non-editiable, use `readonly` instead of `disabled` - either directly in html or via `setAttribute` in JavaScript - and then use CSS to highlight it, eg:

```
textarea[readonly] {background-color:#F0F0F0;})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add an ID value to the form and then add the form attribute to the textarea with the form ID value

```
<form id="sample".....>
<textarea name="aba" form="sample".....></textarea>
</form>
```