# HTML form not sending all data

Tags: php, email, forms

I have a website form where someone can send me a message. They have to enter their name, email and a message.

The form works to a point in that I get the email and the senders name and email they entered is shown in the email, but not the message they enter.

Can anyone see where the problem lies please?

Here is the HTML form

```
<form method="post" action="php/mail.php" name="cform" id="cform">
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" placeholder="Your name..." >
    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 noMarr" placeholder="Your email..." >
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="" rows="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="send" class="submitBnt" value="Send message">
</form>
```

And here is the php/mail.com that is uses (connection details changed to anonymous details)

```
<?
    require("class.phpmailer.php");

//form validation vars
$formok = true;
$errors = array();

//sumbission data
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date('d/m/Y');
$time = date('H:i:s');

//form data
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();                                // send via SMTP - mail or smtp.domain.com
    $mail->Host     = "myhost.myprovider.com";  // SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;             // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = "info@myaddress.com";     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = "mypassword";         // SMTP password

    $mail->From     = "info@myaddress.com";     // SMTP username
    $mail->AddAddress("info@myaddress.com");    // Your Adress
    $mail->Subject  =  "New contact request from ME !";
    $mail->IsHTML(true);  
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Body     =  "<p>You have recieved a new message from the enquiries form on your website.</p>

    <p><strong>Name: </strong> {$name} </p>
<p><strong>Email Address: </strong> {$email} </p>
<p><strong>Subject: </strong> {$subject} </p>
<p><strong>Message: </strong> {$message} </p>
<p>This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}</p>";

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
        echo "Mail Not Sent <p>";
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for, as you say, `name` and `email` to be shown and `message` to be not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need enctype for textareas ... but im not completely sure. Try it, it wont hurt you:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="php/mail.php" name="cform" id="cform">
```

Comment: Just tried that but still no luck. Still no message being displayed in the email. If it might be of help, the "Subject" is also not displayed. Subject is set in php/mail.com but it is not shown in the email I get when testing

Answer (score 0):

Might want to take a look at this similar question

Someone had the same issue and all the had to do was change the id and name to something different

[Issue using $_POST with a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719186/issue-using-post-with-a-textarea)

As to the issue with the subject being shown I saw you commented about, you never pass a subject to `$_POST` unless you are in some other code that is not posted

EDIT 1:

If you are manually setting the subject then why try to get it from `$_POST` as well as trying to do `<p><strong>Subject: </strong> {$subject} </p>` will not work because `$subject` has no value from `$_POST`

Comment: OK tried this - changed id for message in textarea but its still not working. As for the subject, I set the subject manually in php/mail.php as in here:     $mail->Subject  =  "New contact request from ME !";
    <p><strong>Subject: </strong> {$subject} </p>

Comment: Do the values come across correctly as soon as you get them from $_POST?

Comment: How will I be able to test this? I am only using Notepad to edit these files and I am unable to step through code or set breakpoints. Is there another way I can test this please?

Comment: Check my EDIT 1 in the answer please

Comment: How are you running the file to send the email if you can't run or test it locally?

Comment: I have to FTP to live test site each time. Its only a very small personal website and so far it was OK to work away like this. Starting to regret not setting it up properly

Comment: when you run the file, echo out each variable you set from $_POST then add die(); aftewards

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49156/discussion-between-stephen-corcoran-and-hans-moolman)