# Cannot POST all form fields

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a page with multiple posts gathered from a database.
Beneath each post is a comments form with different `id` values based on the ID of the main post.

This is my form:

```html
<form action="post_comment.php" method="POST" id="cmtForm-8">
    <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Comment here"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" value="8" name="id_cmt"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="username" name="usr"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add comment"/>
</form>
```

This is `post_comment.php`:

```php
echo "ID: ".$_POST['id_cmt'];
echo "<br>Message content: ".$_POST['msg'];
echo "<br>User: ".$_POST['usr'];
```

This is the output (regardless of the content in `msg` textarea):

```
ID: 1
Message content:
User: username
```

`var_dump($_POST)` gives me:

```
array(3) { 
    ["msg"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["id_cmt"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["usr"]=> string(8) "username" 
}
```

Why are the `id_cmt` and `msg` fields not POSTing correctly?

Comment: I'm interested to know why $_POST['id_cmt'] is printed as 1 when the hidden value is set to 8 in the HTML code.

Comment: what does a `var_dump($_POST)` display?

Comment: The `msg` content is being passed correctly according to the HTML you posted (there is no value). As for the value of `id_cmt`, there is a mismatch between what you posted and the result, and none of the posted code explains it. Please include any other code that influences that value.

Comment: your id isn't posting too... value set to 8, yet 1 is displayed - see where is that 1 coming from

Comment: You might find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582577/php-post-method-to-get-textarea-value

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` gives me `array(3) { ["msg"]=> string(0) "" ["id_cmt"]=> string(1) "1" ["usr"]=> string(20) "username" }`

Comment: The username LOOKS like it may be coming through, but it already has the default value of `username`, so I suspect NOTHING is coming through as expected. What does `var_dump($_POST);` show at this point?

Comment: @ben: looks great to me. What did you expect?

Comment: what does `<textarea name="msg">This is a test</textarea>`produce in `var_dump`?

Comment: Is this in a completely blank HTML template (aka barebones; no js/css/other tags)? if not try it in a blank template, and a blank php page that does a `var_dump()` and that is it, no includes no nothing. If you get expected results, something else is going on.

Comment: @michi: `string(14) "This is a test"`

Comment: so what's the problem. everything is working how it should... did you type any text into the textarea?

Comment: @RyanNaddy it works successfully on a blank HTML page. I have just updated the main post with more information.
@Prisoner yes of course, and nothing comes through, as well as the warped `id_cmt` value (which should not be able to be changed).

Comment: It also seems strange that username shows string(20), like maybe you have "smart" quotes somewhere.

Comment: There is obviously an issue somewhere else on the page then. Any chance you can pastebin your whole markup for the problematic page? And, on a side note, you shouldn't post the username, anyone can change this and post as anyone else.

Comment: *Baffled* Try putting your `['id_cmt']` and others using double quotes and see what that gives. I.e.: `["id_cmt"]` etc..

Comment: @bmb - Sorry that was my fault. I replaced the actual given username with just `username`, and the real value has 20 characters.

@Fred no luck.

Comment: I have a feeling JavaScript is messing with the data before it gets sent.

Comment: If that's the case, please post code javascript as well.

Comment: @Prisoner It's over two different pages - displaying posts is on `home.php` (and the form is loaded using `echo` statements as part of the `while` command loading each post), displaying comments is on `functions.php`. Everything else works correctly.

Comment: You have 8 (or more) forms on the same page?  Could you be getting the POST data from one of the other forms?

Comment: @bmb That's why each form has the id `cmtForm-<?php echo $row['id'] ?>` - making each one unique.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan and you are getting a value of "1" so maybe it's really cmtForm-1 doing the submission.

Comment: you're not embedding forms are you? because you can not do that.

Comment: Relevant PHP code rendering each form: `http://pastebin.com/0whCYxuE`
Relevant Javascript code: `function toggleDivFast(div){$('#'+div).toggle();}` - that's it!

Comment: I'm not seeing </form> in the loop so that might be the problem? The first form with ID 1 were never closed.

Comment: What happens if you type something in the msg area for form 1?  And what happens when you do that but still submit form 8?

Comment: Like my previous comment says, you're embedding forms, which you can not do.

Comment: @AdyRomantika that might explain always getting the values from form 1.

Comment: Right. Also, @Prisoner is correct on the side note. You shouldn't pass username in the form as that can easily be tampered by someone using Firebug or Chrome inspection panel. You should just use the session variable instead (that I see you already have).

Comment: @AdyRomantika post that as an answer so that I can mark it as the solution. It's the little things... So stupid!

Comment: @BenPearlKahan Q: Why is your posted code in your question, different from the `pastebin` one?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan `Food for thought`. Next time and if there is a next time, it would help us/me a lot and post your `actual code` to find a solution to a problem, instead of having a bunch of people running around like `headless chickens`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the paste in http://pastebin.com/0whCYxuE

To fix your issue:

Add the following as current line 30

```
echo '</form>';
```

And follow up suggestion is to remove line 28 and just utilize `$_SESSION['user']`

Comment: Miraculous. Such a small thing... Thanks for your help, lifesaver.

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy your code :-)